# Sending code to the F# interactive console

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, f#

It is possible to send highlighted code directly to the F# interactive console in Visual Studio 2008 by pressing Alt+Enter on the keyboard, which is indeed very useful. 
Is it possible to in a similar fashion send the contents of one, several or all files in a project to the F# interactive console at the same time? My intent is to test my code interactively, just like before, but this time the code in the file I'm working on is dependant on code in other files in the project. If what I'm asking about isn't the most efficient way to do this, I'd appreciate an explanation of what is. =]

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing directly to do this, but

- you can hit e.g. Ctrl-A to highlight entire files at once
- you can make an script.fsx that "#load"s each file in the project

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at writing scripts. =)

Comment: Yep, scripting is definitely an agile way of doing what I want to do. Case closed.